# What is the significance of characters \. in Unix Regexp?

Tags: regex, unix, grep

characters mean in below unix regexp ?

```
ls -tr | grep "[a-zA-z0-9]\..*[.csv|.txt|.zip]$"
```

Im new to Unix and please explain the above exp and suggest link for learning unix regexp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regex, `.` matches any character. If you want to match the actual *dot*, you need to escape it.

`\.` match the character `.`, so the whole regex matches files that has the extension `csv`, `txt` or `zip`.